# Doubt in following one step of Proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Let G be a finite group whose order is not divisible by 3. Suppose that $(ab)^3 = a^3b^3$
for all a, b in G. Prove G must be abelian.

In the proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/478328/if-ab3-a3-b3-prove-that-the-group-g-is-abelian), there comes a step, where we have established that $a^2b^3 = b^3a^2$.
And previously, we have also established that "Every element of G can be uniquely represented as a cube".

Thus we conclude that $a^2b^2 = b^2a^2$

This is the part I don't understand.
If $a^2b^3 = b^3a^2$ and $a^2b = ba^2$, then how does this implies to $a^2b^2 = b^2a^2$

Comment: If every element is a cube then $b^2=c^3$ for some $c$.  So then $a^2c^3=c^3a^2\implies a^2b^2=b^2a^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $a^2b=ba^2$ gives  $$b=a^{-2}ba^2,$$ which gives $$b^2=a^{-2}b^2a^2$$ and from here
$$a^2b^2=b^2a^2.$$