# EPIC sets in group theory

Tags: group-theory

The following is well known and easy to prove.

- If $G$ is a group and for all $x,y$ in $G$ we have $(xy)^2=x^2y^2$, then $G$ is abelian.

The following is fairly well known and fairly easy to prove.

- If $G$ is a group and $k$ is an integer and for all $x,y$ in $G$ we have $(xy)^k=x^ky^k$ and $(xy)^{k+1}=x^{k+1}y^{k+1}$ and $(xy)^{k+2}=x^{k+2}y^{k+2}$, then $G$ is abelian.

> **Definition**.  Let $S$ be a set of integers such that the following is true.
>
> - If $G$ is a group and for all $x,y$ in $G$, all $n$ in $S$ we have $(xy)^n=x^ny^n$, then $G$ is abelian.
>
> Then $S$ is called an Equality-of-Powers-Implies-Commutativity set, or an **EPIC set** for short.

**Problem**.  Determine all EPIC sets.

**Examples**.

- From above, $\{2\}$ is an EPIC set.  It's also easy to show that $\{-1\}$ is an EPIC set.
- From above, any set consisting of three consecutive integers is an EPIC set.
- If $k,m$ are coprime then $\{k,k+1,m,m+1\}$ is an EPIC set.  This is a generalisation of the previous example.
- It's clear that if $S$ is an EPIC set and $S\subseteq T$, then $T$ is an EPIC set.  So we may as well just look for minimal EPIC sets.

Comment: One quick observation: by [compactness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactness_theorem), every EPIC set contains a finite EPIC set, so we only need to analyze the finite sets.

Comment: Thanks @NoahSchweber, good point.

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2628056), about _Abelian Forcing Sets_, seems to be relevant. The following posts are also related to this topic: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/132807, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40996/.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is given in the paper *[Abelian Forcing Sets](http://www.d.umn.edu/~jgallian/forcing.pdf)*, written by Joseph A. Gallian and  Michael Reid. We have the following result:

> **Theorem:** a set of integers $S$ is epic (called "abelian-forcing" in the paper) if and only if the gcd of the numbers $n(n-1)$ where $n$ runs over $S$ is equal to $2$.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I think the proof of Gallian and Reid is essentially correct, though there is an inaccurate statement on page 3, lines 7-8: if "the gcd of the integers $n(n-1)$ as $n$ ranges over $S$ is 2... [then] $2\in S$".  This is clearly false, for example, $S=\{3,4,5\}$.  What they mean is that if the gcd is $2$ then $(ab)^2=a^2b^2$ for all $a,b$, and I believe their proof of this is correct.

Comment: I've also found that the same authors published a version of their paper [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2324619) in which the above point is addressed and the argument simplified.