# How can I prove $G$ is abelian if ($a \cdot b)^i = a^i \cdot b^i $ holds for three consecutive integers i

Tags: abstract-algebra

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prove that if $(ab)^i = a^ib^i \forall a,b\in G$ for three consecutive integers $i$ then G is abelian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40996/prove-that-if-abi-aibi-forall-a-b-in-g-for-three-consecutive-integers)

How can I prove $G$ is abelian if ($a \cdot b)^i = a^i \cdot b^i $ holds for three consecutive integers, i?

**My attempt**

(1)   $(a \cdot b) ^i = a^i \cdot b^i $

(2)   $(a \cdot b) ^{i+1} = a^{i+1} \cdot b^{i+1} $

(3)   $(a \cdot b) ^{i+2} = a^{i+2} \cdot b^{i+2} $

To prove $a \cdot b = b\cdot a$

Multiplying eqn 1 and 3, we get
$(a \cdot b) ^i \cdot (a \cdot b) ^{i+2} = (a \cdot b) ^{2i+2}$
$                                 =((a \cdot b) ^{i+1})^2$ 
$                                 = (a^{i+1} \cdot b^{i+1})^2$
$                                 =(a^{i+1} \cdot b^{i+1}) \cdot (a^{i+1} \cdot b^{i+1})$

I am stuck at this

Comment: Oldie but goodie. Asked and answered before [here.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40996/prove-that-if-abi-aibi-forall-a-b-in-g-for-three-consecutive-integers)

Comment: @AndréNicolas Hi it might sound very basic but can you help me understand how did we arrive at $a^i \cdot b=b \cdot a^i$ from the step before? Would much appreciate it

Comment: $(ab)^{i+2} = (ab)^{i+1}ab = a^{i+1}b^{i+1}ab$ and $(ab)^{i+2} = a^{i+2}b^{i+2} = a^{i+1}ab^{i+1}b$. Here you can cancel to get $b^{i+1}a = ab^{i+1}$. Hopefully this was the unclear part.

Answer (score 1):

Here $$(ab)^{i+2}=(ab)^{i+1}.(ab)$$
$$\Rightarrow a^{i+2}b^{i+2}=a^{i+1}b^{i+1}ab$$
$$\Rightarrow aa^{i+1}.b^{i+1}.b=aa^{i}b^{i} b ab $$
$$\Rightarrow a^{i+1}b^{i+1}=a^{i}b^{i}ba\ (\because \text{By right and left cancellatin law})$$
$$\Rightarrow (ab)^{i+1}=(ab)^{i}(ba)$$
$$\Rightarrow (ab)^{i}(ab)=(ab)^{i}(ba)$$
Thus $$ab=ba\ (\because \text{By left cancellation law}) $$
It follows that $G$ is abelian.

Comment: Hi Thanks a lot. I also explored along the same lines, before hitting a road block and explored in a different line. My confusion was: On page 28 of I.N.Herstein's Topics in Algebra first para, where he introduces the concept of exponents, he specifically writes $a^k = a \cdot a^{k-1}$ Doesnt this presume order in the way an exponent is decomposed in terms of lower exponents? As I understand in step 3 you have equivalently expanded such a power in both the ways i.e $a^k = aa^{k-1}= a^{k-1}a$ Is it okay?