# A group $G$ is Abelian iff $(ab)^n = a^n b^n$ for all $a,b \in G$ and $n \in \Bbb Z$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

> Prove that $G$ is Abelian if and only if $(ab)^n =a^n b^n $ for all $a, b \in G$ and $ n \in \mathbb{Z} $.

I used proof by induction in the $ \rightarrow$ direction of the proof and I'm done with that.

Any help/hint on the $ \leftarrow$ direction.

Comment: Is this for all $n$ or just some particular $n$?

Comment: That is for all n

Comment: See Arturo's description http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40996/prove-that-if-abi-aibi-forall-a-b-in-g-for-three-consecutive-integers/41004#41004 if you are interested in what happens for single $n$ (the group need not be abelian)

Comment: Thanks @jack. This is what Im thinking. Can I say that suppose it is true for all n, then it is true for n+1 and n+2.. Then I will do what is written on the link to show its abelian. Am I leading to the right path?

Comment: That is a correct way to do it. Peter's way is simpler.

Answer (score 8):

It should read "...for all $a,b\in G$ and $n\in\Bbb Z$."

Take $n=2$ and you get $abab= aabb$. Now use inverses.

Comment: So if n=2, then G is Abelian. How about if n is not 2?

Comment: @Judiel You want the identity to hold for *all* $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, in particular for $n=2$.

Comment: @Judiel You seem to be misunderstanding the statement. It says "$G$ is abelian if and only if *for each* $n\in\Bbb Z$ and *for each* $a,b\in G$, $(ab)^n=a^nb^n$. We could have chosen any $n$ to prove the $\Leftarrow$ direction. The choice of $n=2$ was arbitrary but convenient.