# If G is a group, prove that $(ab)^n =a^nb^n$ implies G is abelian.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I need to prove the equivalence of the following two statements, if $G$ is a group:

> $G$ is abelian $\Leftrightarrow$  for each $a,b$ in $G$: $(ab)^n = a^n b^n$ for each integer $n$

I have done the $\Rightarrow$ implication, but I have no idea how to approach $\Leftarrow$, any hints are very welcome.

Comment: Consider the case $n = 2$

Comment: @SimonS Please make that an answer.

Comment: I see, start with aˆ(-n+1) & bˆ(-n+1) on each side and work towards the "centre". Thank you @SimonS

Comment: See also [this MSE question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/423745/a-group-g-is-abelian-iff-abn-an-bn-for-all-a-b-in-g-and-n-in-bb).

Answer (score 1):

Consider the case $n = 2$. We have

$$abab = aabb \Rightarrow a^{-1}ababb^{-1} =  a^{-1}aabbb^{-1} \Rightarrow ba = ab$$