# About triplets of integers inducing commutativity in groups

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

It is well-known that if $i\in\mathbb Z$, then any group $G$ is abelian provided that $(ab)^k=a^kb^k$ holds for $k=i,i+1,i+2$ and for all $a,b\in G$ (see for example [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40996/prove-that-if-abi-aibi-forall-a-b-in-g-for-three-consecutive-integers)).
Are there other $3$-subsets $K$ of $\mathbb Z$ such that, if $G$ is any group satisfying $(ab)^k=a^kb^k$ for every $a,b\in G$ and for all $k\in K$, then the group $G$ is abelian? More generally, are all these subsets known?

Comment: Interesting question!

Comment: Any $K$ containing $2$ will do. I wonder if you have two distinct integers $k, l > 2$, is it possible to find a nonabelian group satisfying $(ab)^k = a^kb^k$ and $(ab)^l = a^lb^l$?

Comment: @spin : I dont think so, take for instance the integers $3$ and $5$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A group with the property $(ab)^k=a^kb^k$ is termed $k$-abelian, These groups are characterized by J. Alperin in http://cms.math.ca/cjm/v21/cjm1969v21.1238-1244.pdf.

It is straightforward to see that being $k$-abelian is equivalent to being  $1-k$-abelian.

Also, If $G$ is $k$-abelian then the center quotient $G/Z(G)$ has a finite exponent dividing $k(k-1)$.

Assume the identity $(ab)^i=a^ib^i$ holds in a group $G$, for $i=k,n$ and that $(k(k-1),n(n-1))=2$,  Then $G$ is abelian.

Indeed, the exponent of $G/Z(G)$ divides $k(k-1)$ and $n(n-1)$, thus $G/Z(G)$ has exponent at most 2, so it is abelian.  It follows that $G$ has class at most $2$.

Now let $a,b \in G$, one has $(ab)^i=a^ib^i[b,a]^{i(i-1)/2}=a^ib^i$, for $i=k,n$.  It follows that $[b,a]^{i(i-1)/2}=1$, for $i=k,n$, therefore $[b,a]=1$.  Thus $G$ is abelian.

Comment: @Matemáticos Chibchas: your claim holds at least for any triplet, for which two components satisfy the above condition.