# Does there exist a semigroup such that $(xy)^n = x^n y^n$ that is non-Abelian? If so, can this property be finitely axiomatized?

Tags: semigroups

Suppose $S$ is a semigroup such that for all $x,y \in S$ and all natural $n$ we have 
$$(xy)^n = x^n y^n.$$

If $S$ group, then it is Abelian; indeed a stronger statement holds, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40996/prove-that-if-abi-aibi-forall-a-b-in-g-for-three-consecutive-integers).

Does there exist a semigroup with this property that fails to be Abelian? If so, I am interested in whether there is a finite axiomatization of this property for semigroups.

*Motivation*. Let $D$ denote a (not-necessarily Abelian) semigroup, written additively. Then we have an action of $\mathbb{N}' = \{1,2,3,\cdots\}$ on $A$, defined by $nd = \underbrace{d + \cdots + d}_n$.

Now clearly:

1. $1d = d$
2. $(n+n')d = nd + n'd$
3. $(nn')d = n(n'd)$

Thus, ignoring the fact that $\mathbb{N}'$ isn't a ring, we have that $D$ is very nearly a module over $D$. The only axiom that's missing is:

- $n(d+d') = nd+nd'$

which is just the additive analogue of $(xy)^n = x^n y^n$.

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_classes_of_semigroups#List_of_special_classes_of_semigroups) calls a semigroup with your property an _exponential semigroup_.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Consider a set $S$ with at least two elements and the operation $x\cdot y =y$. Then $(xy)^n=y=x^ny^n$ for all $n\ge 1$. But of course $xy\ne yx$ if $x\ne y$.

Comment: Is this a group? $xy = y$ would imply $x=1$?

Comment: Good answer. If you know of a finite axiomatization of this property, do tell!

Comment: @John [semigroup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semigroup)

Answer (score 1):

Hagen von Eitzen gave the simplest example. These semigroups are known as [*left-zero bands*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Band_%28mathematics%29) in the literature. Here is another type of example. Take an infinite [square-free word](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_word) $t$ and let $F$ be the set of factors of $t$. Then $S = F \cup \{0\}$ is a semigroup under the operation
$$
  uv = \begin{cases}
    uv &\text{if $u, v, uv \in F$} \\
    0  &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Since $t$ is square-free, this semigroup satisfies the identity $x^2 = 0$ for all $x \in S$ and hence $(xy)^n = x^ny^n$ for all $n \geqslant 1$.