# How to solve this problem on finite groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group whose order is not divisible by $3$ and such that $(ab)^3 = a^3 b^3$ for all $a$, $b$ in $G$. Then can we determine if $G$ is abelian or not?

Since $$ (ab)^3 = a^3 b^3 $$ or $$ ababab = aaabbb, $$ we can using the cancellation in $G$ write $$ baba = aabb $$ or $$ (ba)^2 = a^2 b^2. $$ What next?

And,

What if we require that $G$ be a finite group whose order is not divisible by a given positive integer $n$ and such that $(ab)^n = a^n b^n$ for all $a$, $b$ in $G$.

As before, we can write using the given condition that $$ (ba)^{n-1} = a^{n-1} b^{n-1}.$$ But What next?

Comment: The classification you want is due to Alperin and described here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40996/prove-that-if-abi-aibi-forall-a-b-in-g-for-three-consecutive-integers/41004#41004