# $n$th power map is an automorphism implies abelian group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

> If $G$ is a finite group and $\phi(x) = x^n$ is an automorphism of $G$ does this imply $G$ is abelian?

I've been reading [this page](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/N-abelian_group).

Def: A group $G$ is said to be $n$-abelian if $(ab)^n=a^nb^n$ for every $a,b\in G$.

which convinces me my question must be true....but I just want to make sure I'm not misinterpreting anything.

If yes, how would I go about proving this. i.e: showing $xy=yx$ -Thank u

I've seen the proof for $\phi(x) =x^2$. For arbitrary $n$ is this the same?

Comment: Do you mean endomorphism, rather than automorphism?

Comment: I'm interested in automorphisms

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1132336/688539

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $G$ be any finite non-abelian group and consider its order $|G|$. Then the map $x\mapsto x^{|G|+1}$ is simply the identity, so it is trivially an automorphism.

For the result you want, there must be some condition between $n$ and $|G|$, specifically $\operatorname{mcd}(|G|,n(n-1))=1$. See [groupprops](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/N-abelian_iff_abelian_%28if_order_is_relatively_prime_to_n%28n-1%29%29).

Comment: Presumably one means to take $2 < n < |G|-1$, at which point the question is nontrivial.

Comment: In general it works for $n = {\rm exponent}(G)+1$. So, for example, for $A_4$, it works for $n=7$.

Answer (score 3):

It is not true for arbitrary $n$,

Being homomorphism only give us that $(xy)^n=x^ny^n$ and it is not enough for arbitrary $n$.

[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40996/prove-that-if-abi-aibi-forall-a-b-in-g-for-three-consecutive-integers) is required condition.(if it is true for three consecutive $n$, you can conclude $G$ is abelian)

**Note:** But you can show that it is true for these numbers $n=-1,1,2$

Comment: From the link you provided :A group $G$ is said to be $n$-abelian if $(ab)^n=a^nb^n$ for every $a,b\in G$

Comment: $\phi$ is an automorphism so the hypothesis is satisfied for my question

Comment: Is this correct?

Comment: @abe:In the link, it is for three consecutevi numbers.

Comment: @abe: let me think for the case it is a automorphism.

Comment: @abe: you can see Luiz answer.

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily true for endomorphisms. For example, there are [nonabelian groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_group) where every element has order $3$; so $x\mapsto x^3=1$ is the trivial map, so trivially a group endomorphism.

Comment: But for automorphisms the answer is yes?

Comment: @abe I haven't thought about it, but I don't think it is true either.

Answer (score 2):

Take any non-abelian group $G$ of order $n$. Then $G$ is $(n+1)$-abelian, since the map $g\mapsto g^{n+1}$ is the identity (hence, an automorphism).  For a specific example, the symmetric group of degree $3$ is $7$-abelian.