# Power map between non abelian groups

Tags: group-theory

I'm trying to come up with the simplest example of a non-abelian group $G$ such that the power map $f:G \rightarrow G$ defined by $f(x) = x^n$ is a homomorphism.

I've tried thinking about symmetric, alternating and dihedral groups with small orders but they don't work, and I'm not sure where else to look - any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Not sure why you think the dihedral groups don’t work. The map $f(x)=x^4$ works for $D_8$. Now, the only groups for which **all** power maps are homomorphisms are the abelian groups.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2131065/688539

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take for example the first (counting  its order) non-abelian group, $\;S_3\;$ , and define $\;f:S_3\to S_3\;,\;\;f(x)=x^6\;$ . This is boringly a homomorphism...can you see why?

Answer (score 4):

A group for which the power map $f(x) = x^n$ is a homomorphism is called an “$n$-abelian group.” Such a group satisfies the identity $(xy)^n = x^ny^n$ for all $n$.

The structure of $n$-abelian groups was determined by Alperin:

**Theorem.** (Alperin) A group $G$ is $n$-abelian if and only if there exist groups $A$, $M$, and $N$, and $S$ such that:

1. $A$ is abelian;
2. $M$ is of exponent $n$;
3. $N$ is of exponent $n-1$;
4. $S$ is a subgroup of $A\times M\times N$; and
5. $G$ is isomorphic to a quotient of $S$.

If you want your group to be nonabelian, the smallest exponent you can get is $6$ (with $S_3$), so you get the example given by @DonAntonio. Note that the map $f\colon S_3\to S_3$ given by $f(x)=x^7$ is *also* a homomorphism (in this case an automorphism) of $S_3$.

The next smallest example is with groups of order $8$; the dihedral group $D_8$ and the quaternion group $D_8$ are both of exponent $4$, so the maps $f(x)=x^4$ and $f(x)=x^5$ are homomorphisms for both.

The smallest example with smallest possible $n$ is for $n=3$ (since a $2$-abelian group is abelian); this is the nonabelian group of order $3^3$ and exponent $3$, sometimes called the Heisenberg group for $p=3$.

**Remark.** The apparent complication of Alperin’s description is related to the fact that groups that satisfy the identity $(xy)^n=x^ny^n$ form a *variety*. By a theorem of Birkhoff, a collection of groups is a variety if and only if it is closed under the construction of subgroups, arbitrary direct products, and homomorphic images, and the smallest variety that contains a collection $\mathscr{X}$ of group is exactly the collection of all homomorphic images of subgroups of direct products of groups in $\mathscr{X}$; this is often called **Birhoff’s $\mathbf{HSP}$ Theorem**, since it states that $\mathrm{Var}(\mathscr{X})=\mathbf{HSP}(\mathscr{X})$. So Alperin is saying that the variety of $n$-abelian groups is precisely the join of the varieties of abelian groups, groups of exponent $n$, and groups of exponent $n-1$, all of which clearly are $n$-abelian.

**References.**

- Alperin, J.L. [*A classification of $n$-abelian groups*](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/canadian-journal-of-mathematics/article/classification-of-n-abelian-groups/7DE7A6C843AABB454A8471A3298EA6C7). Canadian J. Mathematics, **21** (1969), pp. 1238-1244.
- Bergman, G.M. *An Invitation to General Algebra and Universal Constructions.* 2nd Edition. Springer-Verlag Universitext, 2015. Birhoff’s Theorem appears as Theorem 9.6.1 on p. 416.

Answer (score 2):

Write $G=H\times L$, where $H$ is finite not abelian and $L$ is Abelian and finite. Suppose the cardinal of $H$ is $n$, and $L$ is cyclic and its cardinal superior to $2n$.

Comment: I’m curious about your restriction on the type and cardinal of $L$. The cardinal of $H$ ensures that $H$ is of exponent $n$, but why do you need to put restrictions on the abelian factor?