# The order of the kernel of the $p$th power map of an abelian and noncyclic group of order $p^3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

Let $p$ be an odd prime, and $G$ an abelian group of order $p^3$ which is not cyclic. The $p$th power map
$$\phi:G\to G,\qquad g\mapsto g^p$$
is a group homomorphism. Is it true that $\ker\phi$ has order $p^2$ or $p^3$ ?

This is equivalent to asking whether $\operatorname{im}\phi$ has order $1$ or $p$.
Since $G$ is not cyclic, every nonidentity element of $G$ has order $p$ or $p^2$, so every nonidentity element of $\operatorname{im}\phi$ has order $p$. But this does not imply that $\operatorname{im}\phi$ has order $p$, so I'm stuck.

**Note:** I can show this when $G$ is nonabelian.

**Note:** I would prefer a proof which does not use the fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups.

Comment: It’s certainly possible that the image is trivial. Thus two cases for the image, $\{e\}$  or cyclic of order $p$. And that’s it.

Comment: @Lubin If the image is not trivial, why does it have order $p$?

Comment: Well, it’s so much easier to talk about the kernel of the $p$-th power map, as the problem was set up. You’re counting the elements killed by $p$, so to speak. Could be all, could be $p^2$, but can’t be $p$, ’cause that would mean that the original group was cyclic. Can’t be trivial ’cause you’re in a $p$-group, and every element is of order $p^m$  for some $m$.

Comment: @Lubin Why does $|\ker|=p$ imply that the original group is cyclic?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1132336/688539

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is inspired and guided by (and also copied from) everyone who helped me: Lubin, JCAA, and M.darwich.

By Cauchy's theorem (or, as Lubin mentioned, by the fact that $G$ is a $p$-group), $G$ has an element of order $p$, so $\ker\phi\neq1$.

Suppose that $|\ker\phi|=p$.
Then, as M.darwish noted, every element of $G\backslash\ker\phi$ has order $p^2$, so if $x\in G\backslash\ker\phi$, then $|x^p|=p$. It follows that $x^p\in\ker\phi$ for all $x\in G$, i.e., $\operatorname{Im}\phi\subseteq\ker\phi$.
Hence, $|\operatorname{Im}\phi|\leq|\ker\phi|$. Now,
$$|\operatorname{Im}\phi|=\frac{|G|}{|\ker\phi|}=\frac{p^3}{p}=p^2>p=|\ker\phi|,$$
a contradiction. Hence, $|\ker\phi|\neq p$.

Answer (score 3):

Your group is $C_p\times C_{p^2}$ or $C_p\times C_p\times C_p$ by the Fundamental theorem about finitely generated abelian groups. In the first case the kernel is of size $p^2$, in the second case it is $p^3$.

Comment: Agree totally, but in my comment I was trying to explain without reliance on the Theorem.

Comment: Without that you need to explain that if the image is of size $p$, then the group is cyclic.

Comment: "kernel", not "image" in the comment.

Comment: @JCAA You meant that if the image is of size $p^2$, then the group is cyclic?

Comment: Yes, the kernel is of size $p$.

Comment: @JCAA And can you explain that without the theorem?

Comment: Some non-trivial properties of abelian groups should be used anyway (like the fact that if every divisor of the order of the group is the  size of a subgroup then the group is cyclic).  But what is the point of doing this?

Comment: I'm just a little reluctant to use a fundamental theorem to answer such a (seemingly) simple question...

Comment: The question is not simpler than a description of all abelian groups of order $p^3$. You need to consider cases if there are cyclic subgroups of order $p^2$ or not. In the second case the kernel is of size $p^3$. In the first case you need to show, for example, that this cyclic subgroup is a direct factor. This is true, but not obvious.

Answer (score 1):

By Cauchy's theorem, there is an element of order $p$ .Call it $x$ (this means the kernel can't be trivial)

if $x,...,x^{p-1}$ are the only elements of order $p$ in $G$, then, any other non-identity element in $G$ has to be of order $p^{2}$. But, if $y\in G$ and has order $p^{2}$, then, $|y^{p}|=p$ So, you can show that there can't be exactly one subgroup of order $p$ thus $|ker\phi|\neq p$

For the remaining cases, I guess you have to use the Fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups show that the cases for $p^2$ and $p^3$ are valid.

Comment: Why is it that $|y^p|=p$ implies $|Ker\phi|\ne p$?

Comment: @JCAA you can't have exactly one subgroup of order $p$

Comment: Yes, but why? ${}{}$ Isn't it exactly the question?