# Prove that $G$ is commutative knowing that $G$ is a group.

Tags: group-theory

I have the following question I have to prove/disprove:

> Let $(G, *)$ be a group. If for every $a, b ∈ G$ we have $(a * b)^6 = a^6 * b^6$ then $G$ is commutative.

I tried:

I know that we have this rule in $G$ that an element 'squared' is the identity. So $(a * b)^2 = e$, then $(a * b)^2 = abab$. Thus I was thinking of , $(a * b)^6 = abababababab$??? I am really not sure if this holds.

We also have $e = e * e = a^2b^2$, thus $e = e * e * e * e * e * e= a^6b^6$,

so we must have: $a^6b^6 = abababababab$,

which gives: $a^{-5}a^6b^6b^{-5} = a^{-5}ababababababb^{-5}$ results in $ab = ba$.

Thus, since $a,b∈G$ were arbitrary, $G$ is commutative.

I hope this approach is going right. I am not sure if it is the right way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wait, so in addition to $(ab)^6=a^6b^6$ you are also given $a^2=e$ for all $a,b\in G$?

Comment: I know  $(ab)^2=a^2b^2$ holds, but I am snot sure if it is true what I did.

Comment: It would help if you clearly list all assumptions and conditions at the beginning.

Comment: "I know that we have this rule in $G$ that an element 'squared' is the identity. So $(a * b)^2 = e$, then $(a * b)^2 = abab$." This is not a rule. What I think you're remembering that if you have a group $G$ and for every $x\in G,$ it is true that $x^2=e$ then $G$ is abelian. But it's very important to know that it is not a rule in general about groups.

Comment: Thanks for making that clear!

Comment: One approach to every question such as "Is every group satisfying (X) abelian?" is to check counterexamples, i.e., look at non-abelian groups. Here the smallest counterexample is just the smallest non-abelian group...

Answer (score 8):

This is not true for $S_3$. It is not commutative but satisfies $x^6=1$.

Comment: Is there a way you could give a more detailed answer?

Comment: This is  already detailed. The elements are $1,(12),(13),(23),(123),(132)$ and their orders $1,2,2,2,3,3$.

Comment: Thanks. I missed that part.

Answer (score 2):

You need at least another condition to conclude that $G$ is abelian, e.g., that $|G|$ and $n(n-1)$ are coprime, or that $(ab)^m=a^mb^m$ for another $m$ coprime to $n$.

References:

[If$(ab)^n=a^nb^n$ & $(|G|, n(n-1))=1$ then $G$ is abelian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/928772/ifabn-anbn-g-nn-1-1-then-g-is-abelian)

[A group such that $a^m b^m = b^m a^m$ and $a^n b^n = b^n a^n$ ($m$, $n$ coprime) is abelian?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326702/a-group-such-that-am-bm-bm-am-and-an-bn-bn-an-m-n-coprime?rq=1)