# Proof of Conmutative matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm trying to solve this problem.

> Let A and B be square n by n matrices. Suppose that for three consecutive integers we have that $(AB)^k=A^kB^k$. Show that $AB=BA$

My thinking: I suppose exists three integers $k,k+1,k+2$ such that $(AB)^k=A^kB^k$, $(AB)^{k+1}=A^{k+1}B^{k+1}$ and $(AB)^{k+2}=A^{k+2}B^{k+2}$ by adding these equalities and substracting common factors I can get

$(AB)^k(I+AB+(AB)^2)=A^k(I+AB+(AB)^2)B^k$, Which I'm trying to figure what it means. I tried some reverse engineering by doing $(AB)^k=(BA)^k$ but that didn't got me too far.

Any hints on how to tackle this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: There's a version of this question for arbitrary groups, that's a notorious exercise in Herstein's Algebra text. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40996/prove-that-if-abi-aibi-forall-a-b-in-g-for-three-consecutive-integers

Comment: @GerryMyerson notably, the version for groups assume that the elements have inverses, which we cannot necessarily do in this context

Comment: **Note:** We need some assumptions on $A$ and $B$ here.  For instance,
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}, \quad 
B = \pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}
$$
satisfy the equation for $k=2,3,4,\dots$ but not $k=1$.

Comment: @Omn, right. There's a theorem of Ligh and Richoux to the effect that if $R$ is a ring with unity satisfying the identities $(xy)^n=x^ny^n$ for three consecutive positive integers $n$, then $R$ is commutative. I believe the reference is, A commutativity theorem for rings, Bull Austral Math Soc 16 (1977) 75-77. It may be available at https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/S0004972700023029

Comment: @GerryMyerson What about the example I gave above?  Meant to write: *but A and B don't commute*

Comment: @Omn, it's a matter of interpretation. If there exist three consecutive integers such that for *all* matrices $(AB)^k=A^kB^k$, then the theorem of Ligh and Richoux applies. But if all that's being asserted is that there exist matrices such that etc., etc., then your example shows that those particular need not commute. Are you reading all this, César?

Comment: @GerryMyerson It seems he hasn't been around for 2 hours.  Anyway, my interpretation is that $A$ and $B$ are supposed to be fixed matrices.  This is fine if we assume that the matrices are invertible, and I'm pretty sure that's what's missing from the question.  Interesting idea, though.

Comment: There is only one example, César, the one given by @Omn, a few comments up.

Comment: @GerryMyerson $(AB)^n=A^nB^n\Rightarrow (AB)^n-A^nB^n=0\Rightarrow A(BA)^{n-1}B-A(A)^{n-1}(B)^{n-1}B=0\Rightarrow [A[(BA)^{n-1}-(AB)^{n-1}]]B=0.$

Comment: @GerryMyerson Because $A\neq B$ and $A,B\neq 0$ does this mean that $(BA)^{n-1}=(AB)^{n-1}$ and this that BA=AB? What do you think?

Comment: $AXB=0$ doesn't imply $X=0$, even with the added assumptions $A\ne B$, $A\ne0$, $B\ne0$. But why are you trying to prove something that @Omn has already proved to be false?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Sorry, I hadn't checked the counterexample. Thanks. Probably as "Omn" said in order for that statement to hold true more conditions on A and B are needed.